# Database table attributes do not show up in html page

Tags: html, mysql, express

I am implementing a web-app with **express** using **three-layered architecture**. I have **blogposts** as a resource stored in **mysql database**. This is how the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blogposts (
    blogId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    posted VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    imageFile VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    userId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT blog_id PRIMARY KEY (blogId),
    CONSTRAINT id_fk FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES accounts(personId)
);
```

In my `data-access layer` I have a function that retrieves the blogpost id like this:

```
exports.getBlogpostId = function(blogId ,callback){

    const query = "SELECT * FROM blogposts WHERE blogId = ?"
    const value = [blogId]
    db.query(query, value, function(error, blogpost){
        if(error){
            callback(["DatabaseError"], null)
        }else{
            callback([], blogpost)
        }
    })
}
```

Now in the `presentation layer` I make use of that function like this:

```
router.get("/:blogId", function(request, response){

    const blogId = request.params.blogId
    blogRepo.getBlogpostId(blogId, function(errors, blogpost){
        const model = {
            errors: errors,
            blogpost: blogpost
        }
        console.log("model:", model)
        response.render("blogpost.hbs", model)
    })
})
```

This function will be called when a user clicks on a blogpost to find out more about it. Here is the html code that is responsible to show the blogpost:

```
{{#if blogpost}}
    <h1 style="text-align: center;"><b>Blogpost</b></h1>
    <div class="container card mb-4 p-1">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{blogpost.imageFile}}" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">{{blogpost.title}}</h2>
        <p class="card-text">
            {{blogpost.content}}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        Posted on {{blogpost.posted}}, by {{blogpost.userId}}
    </div>
</div>
{{else}}
 <p>No blogpost with that id.</p>
{{/if}}
```

My problem is that no blogpost.attribute shows. My *console.log("model:", model)* generates this output:

> model: {
>        errors: null,
>        blogpost: [
>          RowDataPacket {
>            blogId: 1,
>            title: 'Playing video games ',
>            content: 'ghngjynjy',
>            posted: '2020-02-24',
>            imageFile: 'smiley.jpg',
>            userId: 1
>          }
>        ]
>      }

So it contains values, why does it not show up?

Thanks!

Comment: The Node convention is to call `callback(null, ...)` on success. You're calling `callback([ ], ...)` which is an odd and probably incompatible way of doing it.

Comment: It's also 2020 and Promises have full support in Node. If you use something like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/) you can take full advantage of them and avoid this manual error propagation altogether.

Comment: Is the problem that you're not getting a single model back, but an array containing a single model?

Comment: I do not know what the problem is, only that {{blogpost.title }} etc won't show up.@tadman

Comment: That's what I'm saying. If `blogpost` is actually an array then you can't call `title`, you must call `blogpost[0].title` or better yet, unpack that array before returning it.

Comment: Yes I got it now, thank you for answering.@tadman